# CkZip.class -class file has wrong version 55.0, should be 52.0

Tags: chilkat

Both my java and javac are in same version 1.8 - still I am getting the below errors - Any help is appreciated...

c:\DATA\Chilkat\chilkat-9.5.0-jdk11-x64>javac -encoding utf8 -classpath ".;./chilkat.jar" Test.java
Test.java:6: error: cannot access CkZip
import com.chilkatsoft.CkZip;
                      ^
  bad class file: .\chilkat.jar(com/chilkatsoft/CkZip.class)
    class file has wrong version 55.0, should be 52.0
    Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.

c:\DATA\Chilkat\chilkat-9.5.0-jdk11-x64>java -Djava.library.path=. -classpath ".;./chilkat.jar" Test
Error: Could not find or load main class Test

c:\DATA\Chilkat\chilkat-9.5.0-jdk11-x64>pause
Press any key to continue . . .
c:\DATA\Chilkat\chilkat-9.5.0-jdk11-x64>java -version
java version "1.8.0_181"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_181-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.181-b13, mixed mode)

c:\DATA\Chilkat\chilkat-9.5.0-jdk11-x64>javac -version
javac 1.8.0_181

c:\DATA\Chilkat\chilkat-9.5.0-jdk11-x64>java -version
java version "1.8.0_181"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_181-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.181-b13, mixed mode)

Answer (score 1):

You have JDK 8, but you're trying to use Chilkat built for JDK 11.
You should instead download the Chilkat build for JDK 8  (at https://www.chilkatsoft.com/java.asp )